# Failure deploying RESTful web service application using IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, xml, rest, intellij-idea, application.xml

I am trying to create a simple RESTful web service on IntelliJ IDEA and I am now encountering the following error:

`The content of element 'application' is not complete. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":description, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":display-name, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":icon, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":initialize-in-order, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":module}`

I believe these elements were not needed inside my `application.xml` before, then suddenly I encountered this problem when deploying.

I have the javaEEApplication and Web facets enabled in my project, the deployment descriptors seem to be set up correctly as well. I am referencing Jersey-2.2 as a library to use the RESTful services. My project also has GlassFish 4.1.1 - RESTful Web Service as a dependency.

I am using a Exploded artifact autogenerated from modules, and the run configuration is set to build then build artifacts. The credentials for the glassfish admin are correct.

I'm wondering why I am suddenly encountering this problem, I though that IntelliJ would auto generate any necessary content inside the deployment descriptor (`application.xml`) that it needed. Does anyone have any idea what I am missing? Perhaps I have to reference Java EE 6 or 7 as a library itself? I'm lost here.

Full error log below just in case:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat" start-domain domain1
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\bin\java" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish4\glassfish\modules\javax.ejb-api.jar;C:\Program Files..... 
[2017-02-05 03:16:49,423] Artifact CapstoneIntelliJProject:war exploded: Server is not connected. Deploy is not available.
Detected server admin port: 4848
Detected server http port: 8080
Attempting to start domain1.... Please look at the server log for more details.....
Connected to server
[2017-02-05 03:16:52,358] Artifact CapstoneIntelliJProject:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
[2017-02-05 03:16:53,536] Artifact CapstoneIntelliJProject:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2017-02-05 03:16:53,537] Artifact CapstoneIntelliJProject:war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [CapstoneIntelliJProject_war_exploded] : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 15; Deployment descriptor file META-INF/application.xml in archive [CapstoneIntelliJProject_war_exploded].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'application' is not complete. One of '{"http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":description, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":display-name, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":icon, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":initialize-in-order, "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee":module}' is expected.. Please see server.log for more details.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\asadmin.bat" stop-domain domain1

Process finished with exit code 0
Waiting for the domain to stop .
Command stop-domain executed successfully.
Disconnected from server
```

**Edit:** I have solved this particular issue, having the javaEEapplication facet enabled for the project was a mistake, as it is only a restful web service. Now I face a new problem where the output is telling me `Application [CapstoneIntelliJProject_war_exploded] contains no valid components.` . The server log doesn't contain any useful information. I'm not sure what is wrong with my war, it seems to be configured fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the war exploded issue by recreating the war